# How to write a custom ConverterHelper class in Restlet 2.1

Tags: converters, restlet

I can't seem to find a concrete example of how to write a custom converter for Restlet.  I'm having an issue with an object containing an ArrayList of a base type.  (ie List )

I've been able to painstakingly do the conversion by reading in the object as JSON, converting it to a JSONObject and processing each field individually to create the representation I need on the deserialization.  This seems very odd that I'd have to do this.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You probably have to explain your issue in more detail if anyone shall be able to help you. To start with, if you want json objects, why do you not use org.restlet.ext.jackson.JacksonConverter?

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out.. I wasn't adding code for the score method in the converter subclass.  Once I got that I was able to get my transformation done.

Comment: @MartinOdhelius I suppose I could rephrase my question better.  I have a custom class composed of very simple object types. (Strings mainly)  Do I have to create a custom ConverterHelper class for each one of these objects in order to use them in the code that handles Post/Get/Delete/etc?

for example I want to do this : (+ = @)

+Post
public Representation processSomeRequest(MyCustomObject myCustomObj) {
....
  return some information (JSON, XML, etc) based on data from myCustomObj
}

as opposed to
+Post
public Representation processSomeRequest(Representation obj) {
}